# How to hide welcome page of external installer via Parameters and go straight to Components page in Inno Setup?

Tags: command-line, inno-setup

How to hide welcome page of external installer (also made by Inno Setup) via Parameters and go straight to Components page (in Inno Setup)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean *command-line parameters*.

You cannot skip selectively one page. You can only run the installer in `/SILENT` mode, which will automatically proceed all pages.

See [Setup command line parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).

Comment: but specifying `[Setup]
 DisableWelcomePage=yes
 DisableDirPage=yes
 DisableReadyPage=yes
 DisableFinishedPage=yes
` within LOADINF's file will not help, isn't it?

Comment: No, as I wrote, you cannot skip a single page.